# Access form's Detail's event only triggers on first record

Tags: ms-access

I'm designing a Form in Access 2003.  My goal is that when the user double-clicks on a record (aka Detail), a second form opens.  This is easy enough to do when I start from scratch.

But of course, I'm not starting from scratch.  I've been working on this for a few hours now, have added some conditionally formatted textboxes, fields, etc, and don't want to start over if I can avoid it.

I don't know if I turned on/off some obscure property, but I've been working on this form for a few hours now and the Double-Click event of the Details section only triggers when I double-click on the first record or any other with conditional formatting.

To troubleshoot this, I've gone so far as to comment out all the other VBA script except this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()  
    Me.Application.DoCmd.Maximize 
End Sub

Sub GotoFrmDetails()  
    MsgBox "You Double Clicked Me!" 
End Sub
```

Even with the VBA script reduced to just these lines, the DoubleClick event only triggers on the first record and no other.  Can anyone tell me what wrong? I'd rather not have to rebuild this from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the click events of form sections to be more trouble than they are worth (click event doesn't pass through to the form if user clicks on a control or label, etc).  What I use instead are **transparent command buttons**.

Just add a command button to your form and set its Transparent property equal to True.  Then you can use the Z-order to make fine-grain changes if necessary (send to front/back, send forward/back).

They can be hard to find once you make them transparent, so be sure to give them descriptive names.

If you want the user to be able to double click anywhere in the detail section, just make the transparent command button's height/width match the section height/width.

Move your code from the Detail section DoubleClick event to the transparent command button's DoubleClick event and you should be good to go.

Comment: I HATE that. It's a pain in the but to fix and modify things later, and I think totally unnecessary. I've never had a problem with a double click event on a record/textbox As someone who frequently has to fix the work of others who's done hacks like this, it pisses me off when I see that done.

Comment: It didn't really fix the problem, but it did make the problem moot, which is just as good.

Comment: @CodeSlave: How do you process click events on disabled controls?

Comment: @CodeSlave: I won't argue that they can be a pain to work with (I said as much in my answer), but there are times when they are still the best, or only, option.

Comment: I teach users to click/doubleclick on recordselectors, so I've never encountered any problem like this. To me, Access was designed to work this way, so why fight it?

Comment: To improve the user interface.  I do this almost exclusively on continuous lookup forms.  I lock and disable all of the fields.  I add a conditionally formatted text box so that the currently selected record is highlighted.  And then I add a transparent command button so that the user can double-click anywhere on the highlighted record and open up the detail form.  This whole process adds about 10 minutes of development time per form, but makes the user experience vastly improved because the user has a much larger (and more intuitive) target to hit with their mouse than the record selector.

Comment: @mwolfe02 I guess I simply lock the field, rather than disabling AND locking the field. A side advantage is it lets the user click in the field and copy the text.  The disadvantage is they can tab into the field or might not understand why they can't edit anything. But leaving it disabled and locked still leaves it looking like it is editable, so you have as similar problem either way.

Comment: @CodeSlave:  I explicitly change the formatting of the field when I disable and lock it so that it's clear that it's not editable.  But you are definitely correct in pointing out that disabling the field prevents users from copying and pasting the text.  I've occasionally enabled a locked field specifically to allow that type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the rows are getting their `Locked` property set to Yes, or their `Enabled` property set to No during your condition formatting.

Comment: I have 2 text boxes with conditional formatting.  They are automatically set to Locked=Yes and Enabled=No and occupy about 1/3 of the space I reserved for each record.  However, the Double-Click missfire occurs everywhere I click.  It could be related to the problem, but I don't know how.